# rotating set of shapes as a group

Tags: draw.io

I would like to be able to select a group of shapes in a drawing and rotate them as a group for a specific angle.
So if I rotate using Arrange, this is the effect I get

[image: Rotating selected images]

when what I actually want is for the entire group to be rotated, not shape by shape. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3):

First, **select** all the shapes/objects you need to rotate.
[image: step1]
Then press `CTRL+G` or click `Group` option in the **Arrange Tab**.

[image: step2]

Now you could be able to **select the grouped object** as one object and rotate/move etc.

Comment: No, this does not work. Strangely enough, it rotates the outline only. The actual shapes inside the group stay where they are.